# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Dual boot problem with windows 7

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-7

I have a problem switching back to my windows 7. I have a dual boot system with ubuntu 14.04 LTS as main and windows 7 the other. I tried running some codes today such as

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get upgrade and
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

After the restarting I could not find my window 7 boot option till now. When i acess the windows 7 partition it is quite empty but from disk and properties tell me that there's something on the disk. Any help to get my windows 7 boot option back. Thanks.

Comment: Try running `sudo update-grub` from the terminal and see if it add Windows 7 back to the grub menu.

Comment: No problem! Hope that helps.

Comment: yeah, it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Answered by [Terrance](https://askubuntu.com/users/231142/terrance) in [comments](https://askubuntu.com/questions/623386/ubuntu-14-04-lts-dual-boot-problem-with-windows-7/642728#comment883119_623386) of original poster.

When installing Ubuntu along side of Windows or vice versa a bootloader, mainly Grub is installed. If after running updates you can no longer see your other operating systems try the following:

You will want to run the following command:

```
sudo update-grub
```

This command will basically update the grub configuration, and since Ubuntu installs OS-prober with Grub it will search automatically for any other OS's installed on the hard disk while updating.

Once you run this command, reboot and you should see the additional OS in the list of boot options. This method would work with Windows either being installed as primary or as a secondary OS.